# Logic behind generating random upper and lower case letter

Tags: c++, random

I'm trying to generate an array of both upper and lower case letters at the same time.

I do understand the logic behind generating two seperate cases of letters.

```
rand() % 26 + 65 // generate all the uppercase letter
```

while

```
rand() % 26 + 97 // generate all the lowercase letter
```

I tried googling how to generate both of them together and here is what i got.

```
rand() % 26 + 65 + rand() % 2 * 32 // generate both upper and lowercase letter
```

Unfortunately, they did not exactly explain the logic behind it and i do not wish to just blindly copy and paste it into my assignment. Been searching high and low for the logic behind the `rand() % 2 * 32` when adding the second `rand()` into the first `rand()`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is just boring details of the ASCII encoding. You can stare at it for a while until it makes sense.

Comment: For a start, you should avoid magic numbers.  For example, the first snippet is better written as `rand() % ('Z' - 'A' + 1) + 'A'`.

Comment: First of all, please try to avoid [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If you mean the character A then say so (as in `'A'`). Secondly, reading an [ASCII table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) might help. It should also be noted that your method of generating character (upper, lower or mixed) only works on systems which uses [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). Other encodings still exists, even though they are rare.

Comment: Also it would be good to: 1) Use better generation algorithm: less cryptic and not bound to encoding details. 2) use better RNG.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: I'd say that's misguided advice in this case. The code depends intimately on the ASCII encoding. There's no generality here.  I'd call it outright difficult to come up with an encoding which has letters `A` and `Z`, but not 26 of them, but in contiguous sequence.

Comment: Note also that whether or not you understand it, if you copy it into your assignment, you need to credit the source.

Comment: @KerrekSB - You're right that there's no general way to do this (that would take account of e.g. ECDBIC).  But I'm not arguing this for generality's sake, but for legibility's sake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Observe that the `32` is the difference between `65` and `97`, i.e. the difference between ASCII codes of uppercase and lowercase letters.

Now let's take `rand() % 26 + 65 + rand() % 2 * 32` apart:

- `rand() % 26 + 65` generates a random uppercase letter;
- `rand() % 2 * 32` generates either `0` or `32`, thereby converting the uppercase letter into its lowercase counterpart half the time.

A different, more verbose way, to rewrite this expression would be:

```
letter = rand() % 26 + 65;
if (rand() % 2) {
  letter += 32;
}
```

Comment: I would like to ask, how does `rand() % 2 * 32` generate either `0` or `32`. For instance, i do understand the reason behind `rand() % 26 + 65` because  the ASCII value `65` is considered as a "starting" point while  `rand() % 26` simply just generate a random ASCII character from `65 + 26` onwards but how does `*` in `rand()` works?

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan Read more about the modulo operator `%`.

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan: `rand() % 2` generates either `0` or `1`. When you multiply them by `32`, you get either `0` or `32`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I learnt modulo operator for quite some time ago and i almost totally forgotten about the basic of `%`. Thanks to @JoachimPileborg for the remainder too. :P

Answer (score 2):

An alternate solution to your problem, of generating random upper or lower case characters, might be to use e.g. [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) to hold the upper and lower case character, in whatever native encoding scheme used on the system. Then use e.g. [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) from the C++11 [pseudo-random generator library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Something like this

```
// All letters (exchange the dots for the actual letters)
static std::string const letters = "ABC...XYZabc...xyz";

// Initialize the random-number generation
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());

// This distribution will generate a value that will work as
// an index into the `letters` string
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, letters.size() - 1);

// Generate one random character
char random_character = letters[dis(gen)];
```

See [here](http://ideone.com/O262m3) to see it "in action".

Comment: This answer is great because it does not assume the alphabet that people normally fixate on. There are other letters in the world, even in English text.

Answer (score 1):

```
const char chars[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

char ch = chars[rand() % 52];
```

This works for all character encodings, not just ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

simply just use rand on the whole possible count of chars:

```
int value = rand() % ('Z' - 'A' + 'z' - 'a');
unsigned char letter = 'A' + value;
if (letter > 'Z')
{
  letter = 'a' + value - ('Z' - 'A');
}
```